# Continuous number substitution

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

Suppose you have a textfile:

```
Time step #1 (t = 0 a.u. = 0 fs)
unneccessary text unneccessary text unneccessary text
...
Time step #2 (t = 10 a.u. = 0.24189 fs)
...
Time step #3 (t = 20 a.u. = 0.48378 fs)

Time step #1 (t = 0 a.u. = 0.0 fs)
...
Time step #2 (t = 10 a.u. = 0.24189 fs)
...
```

How can I use regular expressions in order to make the time steps continuous in the form:

```
Time step #1 (t = 0 a.u. = 0 fs)
unneccessary text unneccessary text unneccessary text
...
Time step #2 (t = 10 a.u. = 0.24189 fs)
...
Time step #3 (t = 20 a.u. = 0.48378 fs)

Time step #4 (t = 30 a.u. = 0.72567 fs)
...
Time step #5 (t = 40 a.u. = 0.96756 fs)
...
```

Generalized my question could be rephrased as:

How can a certain pattern be matched multiple times and the pattern

```
TIME STEP #N (t = N * 10 a.u. = N * 0.24189)  with n in range(0,5002)
```

be substituted?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you describe *how* you want the values in parens to be adjusted? I have a solution (an idiom, really) for the first part, but the second part is unclear. Please [edit] to add more details.

Comment: In the end, I would like to end up with: TIME STEP #1 (t = 0 a.u. = 0 fs) TIME STEP #2 (t= 10 a.u. = 0.24 fs) TIME STEP #3 (t = 20a.u. = 0.48 fs) and so on

Comment: To clarify, the pattern is time step `t` means `10*t a.u.` and `0.24*t fs`?

Comment: in an abstract way: TIME STEP #N (t = 10*N a.u. = 0.24*N fs), if you mean that, yes.

Answer (score 1):

There is an idiom ([one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383607/4400820))
of using an incrementing counter in `:global` commands combined with `:s/.../\=` commands. In virtually all cases, you'll start with

```
let counter = 0
```

Though you may use another number if you need to start counting from, e.g., one.

The next step is to invoke a command on the lines you care about, which
generally involves

```
global/pattern/command | let counter += 1
```

Because the increment happens for each line, we can use `counter` to build
sequences. Additionally, if `command` is a `:substitute` with the same pattern,
we can use `//` for a shorthand.

To get expressions into a replacement, which allows us to compute arbitrary
replacement strings, we use `\=`. I generally use a form like `printf()` to
build the target string because I find it easier to read than string
concatenation.

In the end, the full commands are

```
let counter = 0
global/Time step #\zs\d\+ ([^)]*)/substitute//\=printf('%d (t = %d a.u. = %f fs)', counter, 10*counter, 0.24*counter)/ | let counter += 1
```

Running this on your test case, I get

```
Time step #0 (t = 0 a.u. = 0.000000 fs)
unneccessary text unneccessary text unneccessary text
...
Time step #1 (t = 10 a.u. = 0.240000 fs)
...
Time step #2 (t = 20 a.u. = 0.480000 fs)

Then a lot of text and after a while again

Time step #3 (t = 30 a.u. = 0.720000 fs)
```

You may want to adjust the precision on `%f` (something like `%.2f` or `%.3f`,
depending on how many entries you have); the default is 6.

Comment: That was really helpful! Thank you also for the thorough explanation!

Comment: @Lamba you're welcome! General practice is to wait 24 hours or so before accepting an answer, but accepting an answer is a way to say "this solved my problem." Just so you know! [Accepting answers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)